# Antipattern to do a UNION-type in DB Design?

Tags: sql, database, database-design, union-types

I have various 'named objects' that have some shared properties and I think it might make the most sense to save them in the following format in my database:

- `NamedObjectWrapper`

  - ID
  - CreatedBy
  - Name
  - ...

  ***(here is my tagged union)***

  - NamedObjectType
  - NamedObject1 (FK NULLable)
  - NamedObject2 (FK NULLable)
  - NamedObject3 (FK NULLable)
- `NamedObject1`

  - ...
- `NamedObject2`

  - ...
- `NamedObject3`

  - ...

Exactly one of `NamedObject1`, `NamedObject2`, and `NamedObject3` will be set, and the other two null. Is the above an OK way to do this? I suppose the more-relational way to do it, by just storing three tables with all the repetitive properties is fine, but I'll be UNION-ing those three tables together all the time, so I think this saves me a lot of work doing it this way.

Comment: Setting all but one FK to null is a faq & usually an anti-pattern for DB/SQL subtypes/inheritance which is also a faq & best done by variations on a supertype table plus subtype tables or the left join of those.

Comment: @philipxy what does `faq` mean?

Comment: I mean what the acronym stands for but not the official site FAQ.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can you represent inheritance in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579079/how-can-you-represent-inheritance-in-a-database)

Answer (score 0):

Instead you can FK on the detailed objects to the shared information stored on a base object. For example:

`NamedObjectBase`

- ID
- ...

`NamedObject1`

- BaseID (FK)
- ...

`NamedObject2`

- BaseID (FK)
- ...

`NamedObject3`

- BaseID (FK)
- ...

Comment: From the [Book graph Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70518591/484814), hopefully, you realise this Q is resolved by a simple, classic, Subtype cluster, with full integrity.  Of course, you need to rip the do-nothing `ID` fields out, along with its additional do-nothing index.